# AddAttributeToFilter on CollectionMagento

Tags: php, magento, collections, filter

I'm currently trying to filter some collection in core but I dont get why there doesn't seem to work so after couple days, I ask you all :

The problem lies here :

```
                ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=>'customer_firstname', 'like' => "{$data}/%"))
```

Seems I can't get a filter with a variable alone. I wish I could get all firstanme with the piece "Do" in it.

```
$data = "Do";
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', array('in' => array($storeids)))/*Display all orders which have same website than current one*/
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=>'customer_firstname', 'like' => "{$data}/%"))
            ->setPageSize(15)
            ->setCurPage(1)
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try to use addFieldToFilter() instead. addAttributeToFilter() should be used for catalog/product.

Comment: @adrien54 `addAttributeToFilter` is aliased to `addFieldToFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filer by customer firstname with a like condition you should be able to do it as follows.

```
$data = 'James';

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_firstname', array('like' => "%{$data}%"));
```

I would try reformatting your your `addAttributeToFilter` to look more like that.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-8.html

Have a read through here. Specifically "Filtering collections"